# How to use Header, body and Footer in p-sidebar primeng component for angular in standalone component? I followed the documentarion with no success

Tags: angular, primeng, ng-template

I am trying to use a header, body and footer in a  but it is not working even in a fresh Angular app.
I am using primeng v14.2.3. I can't upgrade right now. Angular is V14. I can't find what is wrong.
My component.html

```
<p-sidebar [(visible)]="sidebarVisibleCto">
        <ng-template pTemplate="header">Header Content</ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="content">Body Content</ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="footer">Footer Content</ng-template>
    </p-sidebar>
```

my component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-big-view-offline-status-table',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, SidebarModule, AngularSplitModule],
  templateUrl: './big-view-offline-status-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./big-view-offline-status-table.component.scss']
})
export class BigViewOfflineStatusTableComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  sidebarVisibleCto: boolean = true;
}
```

angular.json

```
"projects": {
    ...
      "architect": {
        ..
            "styles": [
              "src/assets/styles/app/_app.scss",
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/ng-wizard/themes/ng_wizard.min.css",
              "node_modules/ng-wizard/themes/ng_wizard_theme_arrows.min.css",
              "node_modules/ng-wizard/themes/ng_wizard_theme_circles.min.css",
              "node_modules/ng-wizard/themes/ng_wizard_theme_dots.min.css",
              "node_modules/@smart-webcomponents-angular/tree/styles/smart.base.css",
              "node_modules/@smart-webcomponents-angular/tree/styles/smart.common.css",
              "node_modules/@smart-webcomponents-angular/tree/styles/smart.tree.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"
            ],
```

[I was expecting this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCR9G.png)
I tried the same steps described on this page [Primengdoc](https://primeng.org/sidebar) and I got my sidebar all blank.
[sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKhIU.png)
I tried with a fresh angular app as well. Does anyone have any idea on whats is wrong?